# adding animation class to div from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I added an animation class to a div with a variable.

```
 <div class="{{ItemsChange}}"></div>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.addItem=function(item){
  $rootScope.ItemsChange=''
  $rootScope.ItemsChange='animated pulse'
 }
```

Now, I want this class to be applied everytime addItem is called, This is exactly why I am first adding empty string to variable and then the animation class so that animation class 'animated pulse' is applied each time $scope.addItem is called but animation class gets applied only the first time.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your hoping to accomplish, but you might look at [the ngAnimate module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) to help with animations inside of AngularJS. If you are asking what I think you are asking, that module should help you get the job done.

Comment: That's exactly what i am using. animated pulse is a class from animate.css only

Comment: Could you update your question with your actual styles? Also, what directive are you expecting to watch with ngAnimate? You might try using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#animations) instead of just class.

Comment: I meant that I am using https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ for animation. Animate.css is coming from there and so is animated pulse CSS class. Only matter is that I want this class to be applied on every function call.

Comment: OK, class isn't animation aware, per ngAnimate documentation. Try using ngClass instead.

Comment: I tried that. Infact ngClass does not apply animation .Not even the first time. class does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I had assumed animate.css was optimized for Angular animations, but it isn't. To do things the way you are, just reset $scope.ItemsChagne inside a $timeout. So, add $timeout as a dependency to your controller and use

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
    $scope.ItemsChange = 'animated pulse';
    /**
     * each animation inside animate.css is one second, 
     * so give it an extra few milliseconds 
     */
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.ItemsChange = false;
    }, 1100); 
});
```

It's not particularly pretty, but it does work.

***EDIT***

Try using ngClass instead like so:

```
ng-class="{animated: ItemsChange, pulse: ItemsChange}"
```

[On plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fJRrb3N0gWiTffPa2QNs?p=info)

Comment: It still did not. I tried setting ItemsChange to almost everything. Null ,empty string , undefined but still It does not switch :(

Comment: It still did not. I tried setting ItemsChange to almost everything. Null ,empty string , undefined but still It does not switch :(

Comment: No. No errors. Just that it does not animate again once the class has been assigned.

Comment: See my update, using ngClass should make that work. What we want is for .animated.pulse to be removed from the classList once the animation has completed. ngClass should do that.

Comment: No, It still animated only the first time :(

Comment: Thank you so much Caleb . You were really patient all this time :) Thanks a ton .It worked.